# IFeature.Store() method throws COM exception

Tags: arcobjects

I am developing a custom ArcFM attribute `autoUpdater` to update a couple of field values within a feature class. The `autoUpdater` will fire while creating as well as updating any feature with the feature class. Both ArcFM Objects and ArcObjects are used for the development. During feature creation, while trying to execute `IFeature.Store()` method using ArcObjects, the following exception occurs : `"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component"`. The feature class I am updating is participating with a Geometric network and also have relationship class associated with that.

Comment: You need to add your code so we can see what you are doing. HRESULT E_FAIL is a generic error message and says nothing about what the real problem could be.

Comment: Did you start an edit operation and ensure that you have an exclusive lock on the feature class?